# How can I inject dependencies into functions?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject dependencies into functions but it does not seem to be working. Am I doing something wrong or should I do something different instead of trying to inject the dependencies into the function? I'm trying to get the following piece of code working:

```
angular.module('app').controller('usersController', usersController);

usersController.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];
function usersController($http, $cookies) {
  var self = this;
  self.isLoggedIn = ($cookies.get('token') && $cookies.get('secret'));

  register.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];

  self.register = register;

  function register($http, $cookies) {
    console.log(self.username);
    $http.post('/register', {
      username: self.username,
      password: self.password,
      email: self.email
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
      self.isLoggedIn = true;
      $cookies.put('token', response.data.token);
      $cookies.put('secret', response.data.secret);
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
      console.log('Something went wrong.');
    });
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks inappropriate for a couple of reasons; your controller already has those services injected, so it makes little sense to inject them again, and from what I can tell, no state needs to be passed into your function for it to actually work.

This would be cleaner - remove the extraneous `$inject` and clean up the function params list.

```
angular.module('app').controller('usersController', usersController);

usersController.$inject = ['$http', '$cookies'];
function usersController($http, $cookies) {
    var self = this;
    self.isLoggedIn = ($cookies.get('token') && $cookies.get('secret'));

    self.register = register;

    function register() {
        console.log(self.username);
        $http.post('/register', {
            username: self.username,
            password: self.password,
            email: self.email
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
            self.isLoggedIn = true;
            $cookies.put('token', response.data.token);
            $cookies.put('secret', response.data.secret);
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            console.log('Something went wrong.');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. `$http` and `$cookies` are already available in that scope

```
function usersController($http, $cookies) {
    // ...

    this.register = function() {
        $http.post(...)

        // and so on
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Didn't look at it that way. Learned something today!